# Update column with multiple values Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

I am trying update a column with values from multiple columns in another table if two columns match.

Consider the following query:

```
UPDATE application_table
SET    asset_list = asset_table.asset_name
FROM   asset_table
WHERE  application_table.application_name = asset_table.applications;
```

My table structure is:

```
application_table:
"asset_list";         "text[]"
"application_name";   "character varying"

asset_table:
"asset_name";         "character varying"
"applications";       "character varying"
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "asset_list" is of type text[] but expression is of type character varying
Line 12 SET    asset_list = asset_table.asset_name
```

Comment: It's telling me I need to cast the data, i'm not sure the correct syntax to do this.

Comment: Since `asset_list` is an array, are you trying to add `asset_table.asset_name` to the array, or overwrite any existing value with a new array containing only that value?

Comment: @eurotrash, I would like to overwrite. I would like to set this up as a job to constantly check the asset_table and add any new asset_name if they get assigned a matching application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is aggregate the `asset_name` per `applications` value and set `asset_list` to that aggregated value.

Problem is you can't do something like

```
UPDATE ..
SET asset_list = ARRAY_AGG(asset_name)
FROM ...
```

because aggregate functions are not allowed in updates like that.

So here's two other ways to do it:

```
UPDATE app_table
SET asset_list = _asset_list
FROM (
    SELECT applications, ARRAY_AGG(asset_name ORDER BY asset_name) AS _asset_list
    FROM asset_table
    GROUP BY applications
) AS a
WHERE app_name = applications;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKB5k6Lexwzqv6ZbCCdJay/0

This first builds a result set of distinct application names and an array of all the `asset_name`s for each of the app names. Then it updates the table as usual with that array value.

Another way is:

```
UPDATE app_table
SET asset_list = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(asset_name ORDER BY asset_name)
                  FROM asset_table
                  WHERE applications = app_name)
;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8oVWsubXW93n142gtZYLXB/0

This will update every record in app_table, and calculates the array value on the fly for every record.

Comment: Your second solution will force a nested loop join, so I think your first solution is better.